# Put elements into rows and align them at the start and end of each row?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've been trying to figure out how to get four paragraphs inside a div align like below:

```
text1                    text2
text3                    text4
```

Where text1 and text3 are at the start of the div box and text2 and text4 are at the end of the div box. Also text1 will be a bigger size than all the other texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS table layout, equal height rows, and super solid.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; /*for equal width columns*/
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    /*vertical-align: top;*/ /*enable this if necessary*/
}
.big {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell big">text1</div>
        <div class="cell">text2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">text3</div>
        <div class="cell">text4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with inline layout:

```css
div > p {display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align:left}
body{margin: 0;padding:0}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>text1</p><!--
    --><p>text2</p>
</div>
<div>
     <p>text3</p><!--
    --><p>text4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`float`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) and [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control):

```css
#t1, #t3 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
#t2, #t4 {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="t1">Text 1</div>
<div id="t2">Text 2</div>
<div id="t3">Text 3</div>
<div id="t4">Text 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest additional divs to do this.

text1 and text3 go in a div (leftDiv) which gets aligned left in your main div

text2 and text4 go in a div (rightDiv) which gets aligned right in your main div